# how to count number of arrays in nested array using javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, linq.js

I am trying to make a if statement, I need to determine if the nested array has one array. The objects inside removeByNames is what I need to count. Im using angularJS and linq.js. which ever is more efficient.

```
[{
    "style":"smooth",
    "color":"blue",
    "data":[[600,40000]],
    "name":"Subject Property",
    "removeByNames":[["Product1"]],
    "$$hashKey":"object:30"
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array access and dot notation.

```js
var jsoN = [{"style":"smooth","color":"blue","data":[[600,40000]],"name":"Subject Property","removeByNames":[["Product1"]],"$$hashKey":"object:30"}];

jsoN[0].removeByNames.length;
/* or */
jsoN[0]['removeByNames'].length;
```